# Site menu view in Opera

Tags: html, css, opera

I have problem with menu view in Opera browser. 
Menu is made with list items and only in Opera there is extra margin or spacing before last menu item and i can't detect why does it happen.

Website is [here](http://abis2.ru).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float: left;
```

on each li and remove the margin.